# Flex: Changing components

Tags: apache-flex

Hi I want to create a flex web page. Basically I have some menubaritems at the top and when I click at one of the dropdowns from the menubar, the component would change to a page with different content.

How do I go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like the exact component you're after is the `TabNavigator` ([Adobe docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=navigators_4.html)).

It's fairly simple to use. Each child of the the `TabNavigator` component represents a tab page of content (note that children must be containers such as `Canvas` or `VBox`), and the `label` property of the child is used to represent the label on the tab itself.

A very simple web site using tabs might look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    layout="absolute" width="100%" height="100%" pageTitle="My Website" />
    <mx:TabNavigator width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" label="Standard Page">
            <mx:Label text="Standard Page Title" fontWeight="bold"/>
            <mx:Text  width="100%" height="100%"
                text="Here is some page content." />
        </mx:VBox>

        <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" label="Image Gallery">
            <mx:Label text="Image Gallery Title" fontWeight="bold" />
            <mx:TileList width="100%" height="100%">
                <mx:Image source="my_image1.png" />
                <mx:Image source="my_image2.png" />
                <mx:Image source="my_image3.png" />
                <mx:Image source="my_image4.png" />
            </mx:TileList>
        </mx:VBox>
    </mx:TabNavigator>
</mx:Application>
```

You can stack as many child container components within the `TabNavigator` as you like, and their contents will (by default) only be loaded when you select the relevant tab.

If you can be a little more specific about what you're trying to build, there's probably a few more tricks for you out there too. Hopefully this gives you a start though.

**EDIT:** Okay, if you're using dropdown menus instead, it's the same concept but a little more manual labour is involved.

The `TabNavigator` component uses a `ViewStack` component ([Adobe docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/navigators_3.html)), which is basically a stack of content pages where only one is shown at a time (determined by the stack's `selectedIndex` property), with a `TabBar` component to control the selected index. What you want to do is still use that same ViewStack to hold all your pages, but you want a dropdown menu item selection to change the selectedIndex for you.

A `MenuBar` component ([Adobe docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=menucontrols_6.html)) provides the dropdown items, generated from an XMLListCollection data provider. To handle item selections, set an `itemClick` event handler to the MenuBar, and set the ViewStack's selectedIndex property based on which menu item was selected.

Something like this should give you a start, and hopefully the comments help explain it. From there you can add pages, MenuBar items, etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.MenuEvent;

            /**
             * Handle the selection of a menu item.
             */
            private function menuItemClickHandler(event:MenuEvent):void
            {
                // Get the submenuitem node that was clicked
                var selection:XML = XML(event.item);
                // Depending on the label of the item that was clicked,
                // modify the selectedIndex property of the content ViewStack
                switch(selection.@label.toString())
                {
                case "Page 1":
                    pageStack.selectedIndex = 0;
                    break;

                case "Page 2":
                    pageStack.selectedIndex = 1;
                    break
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <!-- Data provider collection for the menu bar -->
    <mx:XMLListCollection id="menuXLC">
        <mx:source>
            <mx:XMLList>
                <menuitem label="Content">
                    <submenuitem label="Page 1" />
                    <submenuitem label="Page 2" />
                </menuitem>
            </mx:XMLList>
        </mx:source>
    </mx:XMLListCollection>

    <!-- MenuBar to provide dropdown items -->
    <mx:MenuBar dataProvider="{menuXLC}" width="100%"
        labelField="@label"
        itemClick="menuItemClickHandler(event)" />

    <!-- ViewStack containing the various content pages -->
    <mx:ViewStack id="pageStack" width="100%" height="100%">
        <!-- Each of these child components represents a separate page of content.
             You should really define them in separate components. -->
        <mx:VBox id="contentPageOne" label="First Page" width="100%" height="100%">
            <mx:Label text="First Page Title" />
            <mx:Text text="First Page content." />
        </mx:VBox>

        <mx:VBox id="contentPageTwo" label="Second Page" width="100%" height="100%">
            <mx:Label text="Second Page Title" />
            <mx:Text text="Second Page content." />
        </mx:VBox>
    </mx:ViewStack>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: hey that is interesting stuff. but my tabs are actually menuitems so there is drop down, I am not sure if tabnavigator would be the UI I want to use. Any other options?

Comment: Check out the edit to adapt it for use with a MenuBar. The whole trick is stacking up your pages in a ViewStack component, then using your chosen method of controlling the selectedIndex. The TabNavigator is nice because it does this for you behind the scenes, but it's really quite simple.